# HTML and Body is not 100% height

Tags: html, css

I have an side divs and a two center divs, The center div is for scrolling other divs that are inside of it. Problem is that page is getting off page

Is it problem with my position? And how can I fix this?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: repub;
  color: white;
}

.container-main-left {
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 300%;
}

.container-main-right {
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 300%;
}

.container-main-topheader {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  height: 45px;
  background: #F00;
  background-color: blue;
}

.container-main-fixedscroll {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container-main-fixedstore {
  height: 50%;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-main-left"></div>
<div class="container-main-right"></div>
<div class="container-main-topheader"></div>
<div class="container-main-fixedscroll">
  <div class="container-main-fixedstore">m
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageleft">a</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageright">as</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionleft">asd</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionright">asdf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-main-fixedstore">m
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageleft">a</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageright">as</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionleft">asd</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionright">asdf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-main-fixedstore">m
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageleft">a</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageright">as</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionleft">asd</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionright">asdf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-main-fixedstore">m
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageleft">a</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageright">as</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionleft">asd</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionright">asdf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-main-fixedstore">m
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageleft">a</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageright">as</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionleft">asd</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionright">asdf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-main-fixedstore">m
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageleft">a</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageright">as</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionleft">asd</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionright">asdf</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Link to this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yc9ptkzx/

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: What is this `position:absolute`? Have you posted some garbage just to circumvent the code fragment requirement? Include relevant code with the question itself.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want.. https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/m7ej2n1b/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.container-main-fixedscroll` needs to be `height: calc(100% - 45px)` because of the height of your header

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: repub;
  color: white;
}

.container-main-left {
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 300%;
}

.container-main-right {
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 300%;
}

.container-main-topheader {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  height: 45px;
  background: #F00;
  background-color: blue;
}

.container-main-fixedscroll {
  height: calc(100% - 45px);
  overflow: auto;
}

.container-main-fixedstore {
  height: 50%;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-main-left"></div>
<div class="container-main-right"></div>
<div class="container-main-topheader"></div>
<div class="container-main-fixedscroll">
  <div class="container-main-fixedstore">m
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageleft">a</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageright">as</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionleft">asd</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionright">asdf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-main-fixedstore">m
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageleft">a</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageright">as</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionleft">asd</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionright">asdf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-main-fixedstore">m
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageleft">a</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageright">as</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionleft">asd</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionright">asdf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-main-fixedstore">m
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageleft">a</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageright">as</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionleft">asd</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionright">asdf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-main-fixedstore">m
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageleft">a</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageright">as</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionleft">asd</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionright">asdf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-main-fixedstore">m
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageleft">a</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-imageright">as</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionleft">asd</div>
    <div class="container-main-fixedstore-descriptionright">asdf</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yc9ptkzx/5/)

Comment: Answering this kind of question will promote spam, bad formatted and unnecessary questions.

Comment: @TalentRunners I think the op got the message with all the downvotes - and fixed the question - now that it is a good answer to a good question are you going to remove your downvote? Also it's a slow day so I'll answer whatever the hell I like, feel free to downvote all you want - I'm here to help not get involved in petty point collecting

Comment: Sure but you need to edit your answer once to retract downvote and the point was answering bad questions will promote more bad question(s) to be asked, not collecting points.

Comment: @TalentRunners, the user is new (2 months) all the downvotes and close votes and comments will teach them how to ask a question in future but as this one was clearly not spam and just needed their code to be added to a snippet, I chose to answer it (I would not have done so if the user had been around longer).  They probably only provided a fiddle because that is all I ever see on here - where's your fiddle, no fiddle no answer, etc, etc

Comment: I hope he learn how to ask now, see somebody also retracted downvote, end of discussion, have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

Please replace

```
.container-main-fixedscroll{
    height: 100%;
   overflow: auto; 
}
```

with

```
.container-main-fixedscroll{
    height: calc(100% - 45px);
   overflow: auto; 
}
```

because

center fixed content height should be equal to total height (100%) - header height(45px)

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/yc9ptkzx/10/)**